# Getting Logger Name into Excel file with NLog

Tags: c#, csv, nlog

Thanks to Rolf's comment in this question:
[NLog in C# with severity AND categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123661/nlog-in-c-sharp-with-severity-and-categories?noredirect=1#comment87344565_50123661)

I am able to record to a text file the category of log message (such as "Thermal" or "Database" or "Mechanical".  I'm doing this simply by passing a name to the "GetLogger" method.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        logger.Info("Hello World");

        (NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("Database")).Info("Here is a DB message");
        (NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("Thermal")).Info("Here is a Thermal message");
    }
```

The text file looks like this:

```
2018-05-13 17:40:47.7442|INFO|NLogExperiments.MainWindow|Hello World
2018-05-13 17:40:50.3404|INFO|Database|Here is a DB message
2018-05-13 17:40:50.3404|INFO|Thermal|Here is a Thermal message
```

which is pretty good.  I might ask in a seperate question how to reformat it.
Now I would like to get these messages into a CSV (Excel) file.  I'm using:

```xml
<target name="excelfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="nLog.csv" archiveAboveSize="50000000" archiveNumbering="Sequence" maxArchiveFiles="3">
  <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout">
    <!-- Layout Options -->

    <column name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
    <column name="level" layout="${level}"/>
    <column name="name" layout="${name}"/>
    <column name="message" layout="${message}" />
    <column name="codeLine" layout="${event-context:item=codeLine}" />

  </layout>
</target>
```

but the output is only:

```
time,level,name,message,codeLine
2018-05-13 17:40:47.7442,Info,,Hello World,
2018-05-13 17:40:50.3404,Info,,Here is a DB message,
2018-05-13 17:40:50.3404,Info,,Here is a Thermal message,
```

This isn't surprising.  I used "name" as a guess.
What is the field in GetLogger called?
More generally, how do I know all the options I can put in the CSV layout?
Finally, is there a good tutorial on using NLog with CSV?  I haven't found one.

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the field in GetLogger called?

You're looking for `${logger}` - see [${logger} docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logger-Layout-Renderer)

> More generally, how do I know all the options I can put in the CSV layout?

You could use all layout renderers, see the [list with all layout renderers](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers)

For options for the CSV formating, see [CsvLayout docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/CsvLayout)

Comment: Thank you very much Julian! Exactly what I needed.